# Rails: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a project for uploading pictures. There are users, albums, and pictures in those albums. I'm up to the point where I am creating albums as a user(haven't done sessions, authentication, or logging in yet, but have done registration). I'm receiving an error after my form submission that Rails

`Couldn't find User without an ID`

I notice that the URL of my new.html.erb is ok:

`http://localhost:3000/users/13/albums/new` (no problem)

but after I submit it, it gives me an error, and the page is:

`http://localhost:3000/albums/58` (problem. no user_id in the url)

does anyone know why my route just changed like that all of a sudden and how to fix it? the error is on my app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:14:in `show' the @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) line.

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (@album), url: user_albums_path, :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>


    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

albums_controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id])
  @photo = @album.photos.build(params[:photo])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to album_photo_path(@album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
end

def edit
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @album, notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end
```

routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums 
end

resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303980/activerecordrecordnotfound-couldnt-find-user-without-an-id?rq=1

Comment: yep I've seen that already, but it didn't do anything for me. same error

Comment: I think the problem is my redirect on album#create...

Comment: how would I redirect to a nested resource? `redirect_to user_album_path(@user)` and `redirect_to user_album_path(@album)` gives me errors because I insert the whole object instead of just the id

Comment: Probably superseded by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701513/rails-how-to-link-to-double-nested-resource-so-that-it-belongs-under-the-top-2

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the nested routes as you have defined(only 2 levels deep) but that increases confusion. It's better to specify as:

```
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way you are redirecting in your create method. When you do `redirect_to @album` it uses the object, its state and the method to find the correct path to redirect to.  E.g. if `@album.persisted?` and the method is GET then the path will be `album_path`.  If not persisted, then it will be `new_album_path`.

If you add the User object as well, then it will evaluate the path to `user_album_path` with the right IDs.

```
format.html { redirect_to [@user, @album], 
              notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
```

Also your routes can be made better.  By specifying

```
resources :albums do
  resources :photos
end
```

you are actually declaring routes for album such as "/albums", "/albums/:id", etc, when you have already specified access to the Albums resource through the nested user_album routes. Either do what [surase mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702685/155586), or better yet, [just scope your photos route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

```
scope "/album" do
  resources :photos
end
```