# Rails: How to link to double nested resource so that it belongs under the top 2 levels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a picture album web app. There are 3 models: users, albums, pics.

config/routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
```

I managed to make users and make albums under a user, as you can see in the URL of album#show:

`http://localhost:3000/users/20/albums/94` (no problem)

however, on that page I want to make a link to create photos under an album that's all under a user (something with an URL that would look like /users/20/albums/94/photos/new), and following my `rake routes` I do have a `new_album_photo` path. This is my albums/show view

show.html.erb

```
<% if @album.photos.any? %>
yes  pics
<% else %>
no  pics
<% end %>


<%= link_to "Upload new pics!", new_album_photo_path(@album) %>
```

However when I click on it, there are 2 issues that emerge.

1. I receive the error: `No route matches [GET] "/albums/94/photos/new"`
2. the URL doesn't have a user_id in it... 
   `http://localhost:3000/albums/94/photos/new`. Could my model be the thing causing this (since albums are owned by multiple users according to my model ? I'm not sure if I should remove the join table and just have the `Album` model be the join table (maybe the join table is the culprit?)

Could this be because of my models? or am I passing in the wrong parameter in my route helper?

Hereare my models in case. 
models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

  validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create

  has_many :album_user
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

end


class AlbumUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :user
end


class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :name, :description
  has_many :album_user
  has_many :users, :through => :album_user
  has_many :photos
end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

routes

```
     user_albums GET    /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)            albums#index
                 POST   /users/:user_id/albums(.:format)            albums#create
  new_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/new(.:format)        albums#new
 edit_user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id/edit(.:format)   albums#edit
      user_album GET    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)        albums#show
                 PUT    /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)        albums#update
                 DELETE /users/:user_id/albums/:id(.:format)        albums#destroy
           users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                 POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
       edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
            user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                 PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                 DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
    album_photos GET    /albums/:album_id/photos(.:format)          photos#index
                 POST   /albums/:album_id/photos(.:format)          photos#create
 new_album_photo GET    /albums/:album_id/photos/new(.:format)      photos#new
edit_album_photo GET    /albums/:album_id/photos/:id/edit(.:format) photos#edit
     album_photo GET    /albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#show
                 PUT    /albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#update
                 DELETE /albums/:album_id/photos/:id(.:format)      photos#destroy
          albums GET    /albums(.:format)                           albums#index
                 POST   /albums(.:format)                           albums#create
       new_album GET    /albums/new(.:format)                       albums#new
      edit_album GET    /albums/:id/edit(.:format)                  albums#edit
           album GET    /albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#show
                 PUT    /albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#update
                 DELETE /albums/:id(.:format)                       albums#destroy
            root        /                                           users#index
           about        /about(.:format)                            home#about
            help        /help(.:format)                             home#help
         contact        /contact(.:format)                          home#contact
```

let me know if you need any more files.

Comment: Album can belong to multiple users?

Comment: hey iouri. yeh I'm trying to make it so that album's are shared among users, so you invite a certain amount of friends and all of you can upload to the same album

Comment: Ah I see. Do you have a new_user_album_photo route? That's the one you should be using, and passing 2 parameters, first one is user, second one is album. new_user_album_photo_path(@some_user, @album)

Comment: nope none... i'll upload my routes so you can see. i was wondering why there wasn't one too... so it isn't nesting properly?

Comment: k i updated it to show my routes. do model relationships affect the routes at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `routes.rb` file should be like this (extra `end`):

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users do
    resources :albums do
      resources :photos
    end
  end

end
```

`album.rb` should be like this (`:album_users` not `:album_user`):

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_users
  has_many :users, :through => :album_users
  has_many :photos
end
```

`user.rb` should be like this (`:album_users` not `:album_user`) and you can add photos relationship this way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_users
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_users
  has_many :photos, :finder_sql =>  proc {"select * from photos inner join albums on albums.id = photos.album_id inner join album_users on album_users.album_id = albums.id where album_users.user_id = #{id}"}

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums
end
```

You should see `new_user_album_photo` in your `routes.rb` and use it like this:

```
new_user_album_photo_path(@user, @album)
```

You can test your route in your console like this:

```
app.new_user_album_photo_path(User.first, Album.first)
```

it should return:

```
=> "/users/1/albums/1/photos/new"
```

Comment: thank you so much!! i see the new routes. so table relationships do affect the routes?

Comment: Glad to help, I didn't know that either, I thought if route was defined it would error out elsewhere if relationships are wrong, I guess it just takes invalid routes out. Learned something new :)

Comment: haha nice to know!! thanks a bunch!!! p.s. i actually had the third `end` on my routes, i just forgot to type it. so it's definitely the model fixing that changed the routes

Comment: By the way, you can add photos to users as well, I updated my answer. Sometimes it's nice to be able to just call @user.photos and get all of them or do counts etc.

Comment: Another note, maybe it's better to change your relationship to has_and_belongs_to_many, but you will have to rename your join table, it has to be pluralized on both sides albums_users

Comment: This is a better solution than what I proposed in the other related question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693253/rails-activerecordrecordnotfound-couldnt-find-user-without-an-id ). Just as a final note, you should probably get the user from the session instead of the request path. Something like the `current_user` helper given by `devise`. It will simplify all your code a lot.